# powershell to return values from text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with users IDs.

userA
userB
userC
etc
This text file changes every day depending on what is required.

Q,
How do I use powershell to return certain attributes from the users in the text file? What I am looking for is

userID, Email address, SIP, ExchangeServer, StorageGroup, Database, LegacyExchangeDN  etc....

All help is appreciated...

Thanks
Bunnioch

Comment: My vote to close is to migrate this to StackOverflow.  I think that's a better forum for this type of question.

Comment: Agree with GlenH7, but while we're waiting: where are the attributes to be found? Active Directory? A database? The same text file?

Answer (score 0):

so assuming you have a text file called test.txt like this

```
1,bob,QA
2,Fred,Dev
3.John,IT
11,rob,dev
```

you can use [select-string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730968) to easily grab information

```
 PS C:\Users\Adam\Documents> Select-String 2 test.txt

 test.txt:2:2,Fred,Dev
```

But this has some limitations since the pattern is a regex if we use 1 we would match two records

```
PS C:\Users\Adam\Documents> Select-String 1 test.txt

test.txt:1:1,bob,QA
test.txt:4:11,rob,dev
```

This can be resolved with more complicated regular expressions but another option is to utilize [where-object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) in conjunction with get-content and provide a conditon

```
get-content test.txt| where-object {$_.split(",")[0] -eq 1 }
```

in this case I have read each line and evaluated the line by splitting it and then comparing the first element

Comment: The attributes will be found in AD.